# Project Euler problem 67 not quite correct

Tags: python

I have the following Python code, which I wrote for the sister problem 18.

It works perfectly for [problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=18), but is slightly out for [problem 67](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67). I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
triangle = [
[59],
[73, 41],
[52, 40, 9],
[26, 53, 6, 34],
[10, 51, 87, 86, 81],
[61, 95, 66, 57, 25, 68],
...
]

def max_adjacent(row,col):
    return max(triangle[row][col]+triangle[(row+1)][col], triangle[row][col]+triangle[(row+1)][(col+1)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    row = len(triangle)-2
    while row >= 0:
        triangle[row] = [max_adjacent(row,triangle[row].index(i)) for i in triangle[row]]
        row -= 1
    print(triangle[0][0])
```

The algorithm is to start on the last-but-one row, and replace each number in this row with itself plus the largest adjacent number on the row below. (e.g., in the triangle partly defined above, `10` in the last but one row would be replaced with `105`.) It simply loops this until it's at row 0 at the top of the triangle, and prints out the first element of this row, which is now the maximum sum.

This gives the answer of `7220`, which I know to be close but wrong. I wonder why it works for problem 18 though?

Can anyone see what I'm assuming or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be that you're using the `index` function. If you have a number twice in a row, `index` will always give you the index of the number's first occurrence.

I guess Problem 18 has no duplicates within one row, the current problem has.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help. Done in java using concepts of DP

```
 public static int max(int a,int b)
{
    return a>=b?a:b;
}
public static int maxSumPath(int a[][],int cacher[][],int r,int k) 
{
    if(r==100)
        return 0;
    else if(cacher[r][k]!=0)
    {
        return cacher[r][k];
    }
    else
    {
        cacher[r][k] = cacher[r][k] + max(maxSumPath(a,cacher,r+1,k),maxSumPath(a,cacher,r+1,k+1)) + a[r][k];
        return cacher[r][k];
    }
}
```